# Reset selected values from react-select within react-hook-form on submit?

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I'm in the process of replacing some `select` inputs in  my app to use `react-select`. Prior to using `react-select`, I was clearing the selected options in the form on submit using the `.reset()` function, which does not appear to cause any effect now.

I tried to store a variable in the `onSubmit` function with `null` as the value to be set to the `defaultValue` prop in the `Controller` thinking it would reset things. However that didn't work. What would be a clean way to handle this?

Parent form component:

```
function AddActivityForm(props) {

  const { register, handleSubmit, control, watch, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    //Additional logic here
    document.getElementById("activity-entry-form").reset();
  };

  return (
    <Form id="activity-entry-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <ActivityPredecessorInput
            activities={props.activities}
            formCont={control}
          />
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="mb-2">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default AddActivityForm;
```

Child using `Select` from `react-select`:

```
function ActivityPredecessorInput(props) {
  const activities = props.activities;
  const options = activities.map((activity, index) => ({
    key: index,
    value: activity.itemname,
    label: activity.itemname,
  }));
  return (
    <Form.Group controlId="" className="mx-2">
      <Form.Label>Activities Before</Form.Label>
      <Controller
        as={
          <Select
            isMulti
            options={options}
            className="basic-multi-select"
            classNamePrefix="select"
          />
        }
        control={props.formCont}
        name="activitiesbefore"
        defaultValue={""}
      />
    </Form.Group>
  );
}

export default ActivityPredecessorInput;
```

Comment: have you seen this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx

Comment: @Bill I have not seen this before! Looks like I should be able to figure out my issue with how they are using the "reset form" button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question based on the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx) provided by @Bill in the comments in the original post. React-hook-form provides a [reset method](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#reset) that takes care of the situation pretty simply.

Create a `const` to store default values (stored in the parent component in this case).

```
const defaultValues = {
  activitiesbefore: "",
};
```

Include `reset` method in the `useForm` `const`.

```
const { register, handleSubmit, reset, control, watch, errors } = useForm();
```

Call the `reset` method in the `onSubmit` function passing `defaultValues`.

```
reset(defaultValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the onClick
`onClick={()=> setValue("activitiesbefore", "")}`
parameter with the setValue value from useForm
`const { register, handleSubmit,  errors, reset, control, setValue} = useForm();`
to the reset button, or to the submit button